# Translation plugin to translate another plugins

Tags: plugins, customization, multi-language

I have installed several plugins, but there are a lot of, which doesn't support my language. I found solutions, which supports to write multilingual content, but can't handle language of plugins or maybe translate it automatically with help of some webservice.

Comment: to translate a plugin you don't need a plugin, it's quicker to use the opensource software Poedit (https://poedit.net/) and put the files `.po` and `.mo` in the directory of the plugin. This is for no-updatable plugins, otherwise, for plugins of wordpress.org, it's a little bit more complicated.

Comment: Note: If you download a plugin from WordPress.org that isn't available in your language, I would highly recommend to suggest translations via translate.wordpress.org so others benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poedit is the way to go fro translating most of your plugins.

WPMl is doing quite a good job, though, at parsing plugins and themes strings for translation purposes. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

There are many translation plugins. I'd say check out `Loco Translate`: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/

***Features include:***

- Built-in translation editor within WordPress admin
- Create and update language files directly in your theme or plugin
- Extraction of translatable strings from your source code
- Native MO file compilation without the need for Gettext on your
  system
- Support for PO features including comments, references and plural
  forms
- PO source view with clickable source code references
- Protected language directory for saving custom translations
- Configurable PO file backups
- Built-in WordPress locale codes

Comment: Loco works great.